WPF Load window without showing it
My app needs to load a window, but only show it when a specific hotkey is pressed.
The window should be loaded in the background and be "ready to show up", but should not show up until the hotkey is pressed.
My first approach to this was to run the following code in the App-OnStartup:
    var mainWindow = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();
    mainWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    mainWindow.Show();

This fails, because the Show-Function seems to set the Visiblity to Visible, so my "Hidden"-Command has no effect.
My next approach looks like this:
    var mainWindow = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();        
    mainWindow.Show();
    mainWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

Already better. This works like it should, but now my window is shown for a second after it gets hidden in the background.
This should be prevented.
My next approach registers the Hotkey in the background and sets the "Visible"-Property of the Window to Visible when the hotkey is pressed.
My startup-Method however just creates an instance of the window:
    ServiceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

    var mainWindow = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();        

    await mainWindow.InitGlobalHotkey(); //<-- Here the Visiblity is changed, when the hotkey gets pressed.

This works, but now my "Loaded-Event" of the Window gets fired only after the Hotkey got pressed.
This is my solution already, but it feels not okay, because as a developer I would expect the "Loaded"-Event of the Window to be executed as the app itself executes.
Is there a more appropriate way to do this?
How can I "load" a window, without showing it?

set the window starting position to be out of screen?

TL;DR, use WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle() which triggers WPF's legwork of creating the requisite native-window ("hWnd") without actually making it visible.
